# How to remove .php or .html extension from single page?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website
eg : [www.abcd.com](http://www.abcd.com) in that there are many pages.
eg : [www.abcd.com/one.php](http://www.abcd.com/one.php) , [www.abcd.com/two.php](http://www.abcd.com/two.php)
I just want to remove the .php from  [www.abcd.com/one.php](http://www.abcd.com/one.php) and not from all the other pages.

I have tried this part in .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(one)/?$ /$1.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: asked. please check.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55057276/remove-php-extenssion-from-a-particular-single-page.   @anibhava