# Remove .php extenssion from a particular single page

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a PHP site. I want to remove PHP extension from a particular page.
below is my .htaccess code.Here **test** is my PHP file name. Please help me out what I am doing wrong here

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^(test)/?$ /$1.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: why down vote here? and please do down vote with proper message so we dont repeat the fault

Comment: There's no concrete problem description in this question. No input paths, no rewrite logs, no demonstration of understanding the basic workings of mod_rewrite. "Remove php extension" is not what rewriterules actually do.

Comment: This code looks fine and will work if `mod_rewrite` and `htaccess` are enabled

Comment: its enabled. when I try for remove extension from all pages , it works fine. but for single page not working. @Anubhava

Comment: Where does `test.php` exist?

Comment: Try adding `Options -MultiViews` at top.

Comment: public_html ->funnel_webhooks->test.php
this is the path 

and tried with adding Options -MultiViews at top, not working

Comment: Now how did `test.php` become `funnel_webhooks_test.php` ? I cannot help with this kind of detailing

Comment: sorry that was mistake. edited my above comment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189644/discussion-between-sibasankar-bhoi-and-anubhava).